# logback and code obfuscation in android

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard, slf4j, logback

I am using Logback library for logging in my android application and it works great.
However, when I export the application and obfuscate the code using Proguard, it does not work correctly (I'm using FileAppder, and the file is not created).

this is my config file:

```
<configuration>
    <appender
        name="userClicksAppender"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender" >
        <file>
                        /sdcard/Test/data/log.txt
        </file>
        <append>
                    true
        </append>
        <encoder class="com.android.gooapplication.model.MyEncoder" >
            <pattern>
                        %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="userClicksLogger" >
        <appender-ref ref="userClicksAppender" />
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

I tried to skip the class MyEncoder and the whole packages of logback in the proguard config file as follows:

```
-keep public class com.android.gooapplication.model.MyEncoder
-keep public class ch.qos.logback.**
-keep public public class org.slf4j.**
```

but still with no success.

what do you think?
Many thanks

Comment: Does it work if you do not use your own encoder in the obfuscated version?

Comment: here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224262/loginauthenticator-not-found-by-logback/50058660#50058660

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution and it work

This is part of proguard configuration file (proguard.cfg):

```
# ...
-keep public class org.slf4j.** { *; }
-keep public class ch.** { *; }
# ...
```

And this is logback configuration file (assets/logback.xml)

Change **pack.of.your.application** with your own package name:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">

        <file>/data/data/pack.of.your.application/files/log.txt</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="ALL">
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

And this is maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: FYI, your maven dependency is incorrect. It points to logback proper and not logback-android. ("ch.qos.logback" should be "com.github.tony19")