# LoginAuthenticator not found by logback

Tags: java, android, android-studio, slf4j, logback

I want to use `logback-android-1.1.1-2.jar` and `slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar` in my android project. But I get following error in Android Studio:

> Unable to resolve superclass of Lch/qos/logback/core/net/LoginAuthenticator; (2251) 
>   Link of class 'Lch/qos/logback/core/net/LoginAuthenticator;' failed

I have opened `logback-android.jar` and I see that`LoginAuthenticator` file exists. Do you have any idea how to resolve this problem ? It could be caused by Android Studio?

Gradle file:

> apply plugin: 'android'
>
> android {
>       compileSdkVersion 19
>       buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"
>
> ```
> defaultConfig {
>     minSdkVersion 14
>     targetSdkVersion 19
>     versionCode 1
>     versionName "0.1"
> }
> buildTypes {
>     release {
>         runProguard false
>         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
>     }
> } lintOptions {       abortOnError false  } }
> ```
>
> dependencies {
>       compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
>       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
>       compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.2" }

My libs directory:

[image]

Comment: Is this a Gradle-based project? If so, please add the contents of your build files to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Apply this it worked for m
[-dontwarn ch.qos.logback.core.*]
[-dontwarn javax.mail.**]
[-dontwarn javax.naming.Context]
[-dontwarn javax.naming.InitialContext]
```

also add (rj.jar) from your java home.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that it can't find the **superclass** of `LoginAuthenticator` (not `LoginAuthenticator` itself), which is `javax.mail.Authenticator`. That class can be found in `javamail-android`'s [mail.jar](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/detail?name=mail.jar). (Note that is not the standard Sun/Oracle mail.jar, which does not work in Android.)

I think you might also be missing a couple jars listed in [1]:

- [activation.jar](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/detail?name=activation.jar)
- [additional.jar](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/detail?name=additionnal.jar)

I would try copying the 3 jars to your libs directory (overwriting your existing mail.jar) and then perhaps a clean build.

[1] https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/wiki/Appender-Notes#smtpappender